# Where will I do request in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, request, fetch

[My app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWa3D.png)

Where can I make a axios request and save the data in redux? In which component should I do this? My API is https://www.weatherapi.com/api-explorer.aspx, I only need to make 1 request for the whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main component in the onMounted/created hook